# JavaFX: setting colors in AreaChart without depending on order

Tags: css, javafx

I have an `ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>>` that I'm plotting in an `AreaChart`.  This is constructed from an `ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableList<XY>>`.  I have a .css file that contains ten colors like:

```
.default-color0.chart-legend-item-symbol { -fx-background-color:    #d46d00;}
.default-color0.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke:                      #d46d00;}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-line {-fx-stroke:                 #d46d00;}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill {-fx-fill:                   #d46d00;}

.default-color1.chart-legend-item-symbol { -fx-background-color:    #000000;}
.default-color1.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke:                      #000000;}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-line {-fx-stroke:                 #000000;}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill {-fx-fill:                   #000000;}
```

What I'd love to do is have an `ImmutableMap<String, Color>` which I could use to set the color of each series according to the Series label, but afaik it isn't possible to change the colors in code, I *have* to use CSS.

Is there a way I can write the CSS to choose the colors for each series based on the label, or otherwise give each one a custom variable name that can be used to select the color in the plot?

Update: I provided an MWE, in which I try to implement the suggestions below.

(Had to ask a separate question just to get the MWE working: [CSS+JavaFX: Could not resolve X while resolving lookups for Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470598/cssjavafx-could-not-resolve-x-while-resolving-lookups-for-y?noredirect=1#comment95749398_54470598) ultimately I fixed it by adding * to the root in the CSS)

dummy.css:

```
.root * {
    -chart0-color: red;
    -chart1-color: black;
}

.default-color0.chart-legend-item-symbol { -fx-background-color:    -chart0-color;} 
.default-color0.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke:                      -chart0-color;}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-line {-fx-stroke:                 -chart0-color;}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill {-fx-fill:                   -chart0-color;}

.default-color1.chart-legend-item-symbol { -fx-background-color:    -chart1-color;}
.default-color1.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke:                      -chart1-color;}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-line {-fx-stroke:                 -chart1-color;}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill {-fx-fill:                   -chart1-color;}
```

CSSAreaChartMWE.java:

```
package csstest;

import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CSSAreaChartMWE extends Application {

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> functionToData(Function<Double, Double> f, double minx, double maxx) {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        double dx = (maxx-minx)/(100);
        double x = minx;

        while (x < maxx) {
            list.add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, f.apply(x))); x+=dx;
        }
        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        double minx = 0;
        double maxx = 6*Math.PI;
        double amp = 5;
        double period = (maxx-minx)/6;

        Series<Number, Number> sin = new Series<>("sin", functionToData((x) -> amp*Math.sin(x/period), minx, maxx));
        Series<Number, Number> cos = new Series<>("cos", functionToData((x) -> amp*Math.cos(x/period), minx, maxx));


        ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> series = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        series.add(sin);
        series.add(cos);

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        AreaChart chart = new AreaChart(xAxis, yAxis, series);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("dummy.css").toExternalForm());

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        chart.setStyle("-chart1-color: pink; -chart2-color: green");
        box.setStyle("-chart1-color: orange; -chart2-color: blue");
        primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setStyle("-chart1-color: darkgrey; -chart2-color: lightgrey");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I tried `setStyle()` on various nodes, but it never had any effect; the original red and black stayed.  I imagine I'm not understanding the suggestion correctly?

Comment: [`XYChart.Series.nodeProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html#nodeProperty) might help.

Comment: This should help https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5094893

Comment: In the css file, you can do `.root{ chart1-color: #f00; chart2-color: #0f0; }`. Then you could set `-fx-stroke: chart1-color;` for the first chart series, set `-fx-stroke: chart2-color;` for the second chart, and etc.
In the code after the stage has been shown, access the root pane, vbox or whatever, and do `setStyle("chart1-color: " + immutableMap.get(seriesName) + ";"

Comment: @BlakeOrdway I gave this a try without luck, see above.

Comment: @Sedrick I copied that in and had problems that were solved by replacing `.root{...}` with `.root * {...}` any reason why that would presumably work for them but not me?

Comment: I am not sure. I haven't look deeply at that code. It may be very old code.