# CSS+JavaFX: Could not resolve X while resolving lookups for Y

Tags: css, javafx

I'm brand new to CSS, and trying to make a MWE for a chart in JavaFX.  I've been able to make it work in some cases, but my problems pop up when I try to define variables in root.  What I want to do eventually is update the values of `chart0-color` and `chart1-color` in code, but for now I'm trying to just define them as variables in the .css.

I ran it through CSSLint and it gave some warnings about adjoining classes, but no errors.

If I replace `-chart0-color` and `-chart1-color` with any other color string like `red` or `green`, the problem goes away.

Do you see any problems in my css?

dummy.css:

```
.root{
    -chart0-color: #ff0000;
    -chart1-color: #00ff00;
}

.default-color0.chart-legend-item-symbol { -fx-background-color:    -chart0-color;}
.default-color0.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke:                      -chart0-color;}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-line {-fx-stroke:                 -chart0-color;}
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill {-fx-fill:                   -chart0-color;}

.default-color1.chart-legend-item-symbol { -fx-background-color:    -chart1-color;}
.default-color1.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke:                      -chart1-color;}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-line {-fx-stroke:                 -chart1-color;}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill {-fx-fill:                   -chart1-color;}
```

CSSAreaChartMWE.java:

```
package csstest;

import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CSSAreaChartMWE extends Application {

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> functionToData(Function<Double, Double> f, double minx, double maxx) {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        double dx = (maxx-minx)/(100);
        double x = minx;

        while (x < maxx) {
            list.add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, f.apply(x))); x+=dx;
        }
        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        double minx = 0;
        double maxx = 6*Math.PI;
        double amp = 5;
        double period = (maxx-minx)/6;

        Series<Number, Number> sin = new Series<>("sin", functionToData((x) -> amp*Math.sin(x/period), minx, maxx));
        Series<Number, Number> cos = new Series<>("cos", functionToData((x) -> amp*Math.cos(x/period), minx, maxx));


        ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> series = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        series.add(sin);
        series.add(cos);

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        AreaChart chart = new AreaChart(xAxis, yAxis, series);
        chart.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("dummy.css").toExternalForm());
        chart.setStyle("chart1-color: black; chart2-color: red");

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and finally, the errors:

```
WARNING: Could not resolve '-chart0-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-fill' from rule '*.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill' in stylesheet file:/*****/csstest/dummy.css
Jan 31, 2019 6:01:09 PM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-chart0-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-stroke' from rule '*.default-color0.chart-series-area-line' in stylesheet file:/*****/classes/csstest/dummy.css
.......
```

Comment: The chart doesn't have style class `root`, does it?

Comment: No...I looked this up and found that I could fix it by changing it in the .css to .root * {}.  I gather the * adds the class to every applicable node?  That does solve my problem but I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: If you're not familiar with css selectors, you should definetly take a look at the basic ones (some are unavailable in javafx). `*` matches any node. Adding the stylesheet to the scene instead should result in `.root` matching the scene root. Replaying `.root` with `.chart` in the css stylesheet may also work.

Comment: I think the main problem is you are adding the stylesheet to the chart rather than the scene. The chart doesn't have the "root" class. The .root selector is fine if you add the stylesheet to the whole scene, as the specification says looked-up colors are inherited. Modena uses .root to define its looked-up colors.

But another problem is you used different names in the Java than the CSS. I'm not familiar with charts, so there might be other problems with your selectors.